# Mysql Column count error eventought nbr of col is right

Tags: php, sql, mysql, wordpress, forms

I'm trying to make a basic form in PHP(Wordpress) with checkboxes. The user has to select a store and then click on desired checkboxes.

Once the form is submitted I need to save that form data as store_id => data_ID, where every data_ID is a new line in the db,and data_id contains the checkboxes ID. So it will look like this :

```
store_id | data_id
556 => 5134
556 => 5135
556 => 5136
..
```

On submit, my $_POST looks like this

> "Array ( [store_id] => Array ( [0] => 246 ) [data_id] => Array ( [0] => 259 [1] => 102 ) ) 1"

Here is my code:

```
$values = array();
$place_holders = array();
$query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `$mytable`( store_id, data_id)  VALUES ";
foreach ($_POST as $_POST['store_id'] => $_POST['data_id']) {
        $values[$_POST['store_id']] = $_POST['data_id'];
        $place_holders[] = "('%d')"; 
}

$query .= implode(', ', $place_holders);
//die(var_dump($values));
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("$query ", $values));
```

But this always return this Mysql error

> WordPress database error: [Column count doesn't match value count at row 1]
> INSERT IGNORE INTO `wp_mytable`( store_id, data_id) VALUES ('0'), ('0')
> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

I don't understand this error since I've looked at the docs and it says it should be fine since I've specified explicitly witch table in need to write on.
Any idea ? thanks

I tried a lot of things, many trial and error but nothing worked

Comment: Please format your post correctly. As it stands, it is hard to follow.

Comment: I tried to post it but it would not let me post unless I had a shitton of spaces in front of every line even thought I've spent 15mn formating in completely

Comment: `foreach ($_POST as $_POST['store_id'] => $_POST['data_id'])` - This one is _very_ odd and probably not what you want. If you just get one store id and one list of data id's, then skip the loop and just fetch the values you want directly from the `$_POST`-data. Right now, you're iterating through the complete `$_POST`-array, overwriting the value in `$values` when the store id are the same (which seems like it always will be), but will keep adding new entries to `$place_holders`. That would make the place holders and values unaligned.

Comment: Hi @M.Eriksson, Oooh okay that explain those weird behavior I had previously. So yeah store_id will be the same for every data_id. So, I need to extract the data_id array from post and then what ? Make a foreach with the data_id array where the store_id is the key ? thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

For your code to run properly the `store_id` array item must be equal to the `data_id` array item but the example array you post is not

```
Array ( [store_id] => Array ( [0] => 246 ) [data_id] => Array ( [0] => 259 [1] => 102 ) )
```

So let's assume the `store_id` and `data_id` array items are equal like so

```
Array ( [store_id] => Array ( [0] => 246 [1] => 247 ) [data_id] => Array ( [0] => 259 [1] => 102 ) )
```

Then your code would be as follow:

```
<?php
    $values = array();
    
    //we use str_repeat to get the number of placeholders
    //$place_holders = array(); 
    
    $query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `$mytable`( store_id, data_id) VALUES(". str_repeat('%d,', count($_POST['store_id']) - 1). "%d)";
    
    foreach ($_POST['store_id'] as $key => $val){
           // In this is way $val will be the value for $_POST['store_id']
           // Then to get value for $_POST['data_id'] you use the $key 
             
            $values[$val] = $_POST['data_id'][$key];
    
           // $place_holders[] = "('%d')"; 
    }
    
    //$query .= implode(', ', $place_holders);
    //die(var_dump($values));
    
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("$query", $values));
```

But in a situation where the `store_id` array will just be one item and you want that item to be equal to each item on the `data_id` array

Then your code should be like so:

```
<?php
    $values = array();

    $query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `$mytable`( store_id, data_id) VALUES(". str_repeat('%d,', count($_POST['data_id']) - 1). "%d)";

foreach ($_POST['data_id'] as $key => $val){
    $values[$_POST['store_id'][0]] = $val;
}
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("$query", $values));
```

Comment: thanks for everyone's help, I got help from a friend and turns out it's way simpler than I thought:
```
$seller_id = $_POST['store_id'][0];
$data_ids = $_POST['data_id'];
    foreach ($data_ids as $data_id) {
        $wpdb->insert(
            $attribut_table,
            array(
                'store_id' => $seller_id,
                'data_id' => intval($data_id) 
            )
        );
    }
``